# Convert vim syntax highlighting for use with gedit

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, gedit

Is there an easy way to convert vim syntax highlighting definitions for use with GtkSourceView/gedit?

Comment: I think he doesn't want a colorscheme but a syntax definition.